# How can I print multiple indexes of a certain value in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing

I'm just learning python and I have a problem. how can I print multiple indexes of a certain value in a dictionary? In particular, I want to print the index of each element of the dictionary_title array which has `gender_ids` as the key.

```
dictionary_title={
{'label': 'Green', 'genre_ids': 878},
{'label': 'Pink', 'genre_ids': 16},
{'label': 'Orange', 'genre_ids': 28},
{'label': 'Yellow', 'genre_ids': 9648},
{'label': 'Red', 'genre_ids': 878},
{'label': 'Brown', 'genre_ids': 12},
{'label': 'Black', 'genre_ids': 28},
{'label': 'White', 'genre_ids': 14},
{'label': 'Blue', 'genre_ids': 28},
{'label': 'Light Blue', 'genre_ids': 10751},
{'label': 'Magenta', 'genre_ids': 28},
{'label': 'Gray', 'genre_ids': 28}}
```

This is my code:

```
   for values in dictionary_title["genre_ids"]: 
   for item in values:       
       if item == 28:      
           print(values.index(item))
```

For example, I want to print index:2,6,8,10,11 which are the indexes of the items with the key, `genre_ids`=28. How can I do it?

Comment: Your top-level object `dictionary_title` is not a dictionary, it is a set.

Comment: `enumerate(dictionary_title)`

Comment: 2nd, dictionaries aren't stored in the order they are entered. There's no index for the items in the dictionary (except the keys). You could use a list instead of a set if you want to preserve the order of the items and be able to index them.

Comment: thank you guys. So i don't udenrstant dictionary use key and values...so dictionary_title there is a key and a value for each element so why is dictionary_title not a dictionary?

Comment: dictionary_title CONTAINS dictionaries, but it itself is a set. Compare `my_set = {a, b, c}` and `my_dict = {a:b, c:d, e:f}`

Comment: @Elly What you've shown as your declaration for dictionary_title is syntactically flawed. You're using set syntax. However, items within a set need to be hashable and dictionaries are not hashable. Try running your own code and you'll see

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension with `enumerate`.

```py
dictionary_title=[
{'label': 'Green', 'genre_ids': 878},
{'label': 'Pink', 'genre_ids': 16},
{'label': 'Orange', 'genre_ids': 28},
{'label': 'Yellow', 'genre_ids': 9648},
{'label': 'Red', 'genre_ids': 878},
{'label': 'Brown', 'genre_ids': 12},
{'label': 'Black', 'genre_ids': 28},
{'label': 'White', 'genre_ids': 14},
{'label': 'Blue', 'genre_ids': 28},
{'label': 'Light Blue', 'genre_ids': 10751},
{'label': 'Magenta', 'genre_ids': 28},
{'label': 'Gray', 'genre_ids': 28}]

res = [i for i, o in enumerate(dictionary_title) if o['genre_ids'] == 28]
print(res)
```

Comment: thank you guy but i have this error: res = [i for i, o in enumerate(dictionary_title) if o['genre_ids'] == 28]
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not 'str'

Comment: You must have made a typo; try copypasting @Unmitigated's answer.

Comment: @Elly The code in my answer does work. See it in action [here](https://ideone.com/Dl6vQV). There might be a mistake elsewhere in your code.

Answer (score 1):

"dictionary title" must be a list!!! I leave you the code of how to do it :-)

```
dictionary_title=[
{'label': 'Green', 'genre_ids': 878},
{'label': 'Pink', 'genre_ids': 16},
{'label': 'Orange', 'genre_ids': 28},
{'label': 'Yellow', 'genre_ids': 9648},
{'label': 'Red', 'genre_ids': 878},
{'label': 'Brown', 'genre_ids': 12},
{'label': 'Black', 'genre_ids': 28},
{'label': 'White', 'genre_ids': 14},
{'label': 'Blue', 'genre_ids': 28},
{'label': 'Light Blue', 'genre_ids': 10751},
{'label': 'Magenta', 'genre_ids': 28},
{'label': 'Gray', 'genre_ids': 28}]

for idx in range(0, len(dictionary_title)):
    if dictionary_title[idx]["genre_ids"] == 28:
        print(idx)
```

You can also do it using different loop styles.

Style 2: Loop using enumerate()

```
for enumerate_item in enumerate(dictionary_title):
    if enumerate_item[1]["genre_ids"] == 28:
        print(enumerate_item[0])
```

Style 3: Loop using enumerate() just in other way...

```
for idx, dict in enumerate(dictionary_title):
    if dict['genre_ids'] == 28:
        print(idx)
```

Style 4: Loop using list comprehension

```
rest = [enumerate_item[0] for enumerate_item in enumerate(dictionary_title) if enumerate_item[1]['genre_ids'] == 28]
print(rest)
```

Style 5: Loop using list comprehension just in other way...

```
rest = [(idx) for idx, dict in enumerate(dictionary_title) if dict['genre_ids'] == 28]
print(rest)
```